# How to solve transcendental hyperbolic equation

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, transcendental-equations

How can I solve the functional relation
$$
    e^{-af'(x)}\cosh( f(x) ) = bx
$$
for $f(x)$? It would suffice to solve for $x>0$, $a>0$ and $b>0$.

Answer (score 1):

for $a$:
$-{\frac {1}{f \left( x \right) }\ln  \left( {\frac {bx}{\cosh \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}f \left( x \right)  \right) }} \right) }
$
for $b$:
${\frac {{{\rm e}^{-af \left( x \right) }}\cosh \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}x}}f \left( x \right)  \right) }{x}}
$
for $x$ no chance

Comment: I edited the question to make intent clearer.